# Como remover arquivos CSS e Javascript de bloqueio no Blogger, como o Widgets.js?

Tags: javascript, css, otimização, blogger

Eu estou a tentar optimizar a velocidade de carregamento do meu site Blogger, removendo arquivos CSS desnecessários dos quais eu não faço uso, nem tenciono fazer futuramente. Como por exemplo:

```
<link type="text/css" href="https://www.blogger.com/.../widget_css_bundle.css"/>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//www.blogger.com/.../widgets.js"></script>
```

Eu já removi todos os arquivos externos do `<head>` do meu tema/template, mas continua dizendo para otimizar estes dois links:

```
https://www.blogger.com/dyn-css/authorization.css?targetBlogID=8710304722259354525&zx=2381a04e-88ac-4d76-996f-5a33d1055397  
https://www.blogger.com/static/v1/widgets/3645911276-widget_css_bundle.css
```

Só que esses links só aparecem na `view-source` da página, eu nem sei como eles estão a ser gerados e nem como otimizá-los.

Como remover Widgets JavaScript (Widgets.js) e CSS padrão do Blogger, para aumentar o *page speed*. Alguma ideia?

Comment: Seja mais específica na sua dúvida. Eles devem estar sendo adicionados na página por javascript, mas ainda não entendi o que você define por "css de bloqueio", qual problema exatamente você está tendo?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Estes arquivos são implementados automaticamente pelo Blogger, não pelo template, por isso é que no template não encontras onde é que eles estão a ser gerados.

Remover estes arquivos pode melhorar a velocidade de carregamento do seu site Blogger. Mas se estiveres a utilizar widgets ou gadgets do Blogger, é extremamente **recomendado não fazer isto**!
Isto é apenas recomendado a Bloggers que desenvolvem os seus próprios temas (*templates*) e que quase nunca usam widgets ou gadgets.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

## Remover o CSS padrão do Blogger

1- Nas configurações do Blogger, navegue até ao Template → Edit HTML
2- Procure & substitua:

```
<b:skin><![CDATA[
```

**pelo seguinte:**

```
&lt;style type=&quot;text/css&quot;&gt;
&lt;!-- /*<b:skin><![CDATA[*/]]></b:skin>
<style type='text/css'>
```

3- Procure & substitua (encerramento da tag acima)

```
]]></b:skin>
```

**pelo seguinte:**

```
</style>
```

---

## Remover o JS padrão do Blogger

1- Navegue até ao Template → Edit HTML
2- Procure & substitua:

```
</body>
```

**pelo seguinte:**

```
&lt;!---</body>---&gt;&lt;/body&gt;
```

> Feito este hack para remover os ficheiros JS, irá notar que no final da
>   sua página/Blog, vai aparecer uma setinha assim: `-->`, no final do
>   encerramento da tag `</body>` como se encontra em vários Blogs que usam este método para dispensar o carregamento destes arquivos, mas com umas poucas modificações de
>   estilos CSS podemos tornar esta seta "invisível" ou menos visível
>   mudando a cor do texto do `<body>`, como no exemplo abaixo, e depois
>   então dar novamente a cor desejada para o suposto 'body' num elemento
>   *wrapper/container* com um nível mais abaixo se é que me fiz entender:
>
> ```
> body {color:#F2F2F2; /* Escolha uma cor para que a seta fique igual à cor de fundo do body */}
> #elementoWrapper {color:#000; /* Dê novamente a cor desejada para o body */}
> ```
>
> ```
> <body>
>     <div id="elementoWrapper">
>         Conteúdo aqui...
>     </div>
> </body>
> ```

Feito isto, agora os seus ficheiros padrão CSS e JS não serão carregados.

Comment: Entendi tudo e funcionou... Só que não aparece --> porque que é um comentário.

Comment: Nice, Melhor ainda @CarlaVieira ! Eu já adoptei este método em vários temas Blogger em que trabalhei e de algum jeito essa seta costuma ficar sempre visível. ^^

Answer (score 0):

No meu caso não solucionou, mas descobri uma nova solução (que agora percebi ser igual a solução acima para o caso do JS).
Basta substituir o:

```
<head>
```

por:

```
&lt;!--<head>--&gt;&lt;head&gt;
```

Não sei o motivo, provavelmente alguma atualização do Blogger ou algo relacionado com o meu template. O carregamento do .css estava exatamente abaixo do `<head>` no meu caso, não sei do seu.